# rmarkdown indentation is not working

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to create list in rmarkdown

````
```{r}
cat("* 1. CPU\n\n")
cat("+ >80%, investigate the load on JVM\n\n")
cat("+ >90%, add more CPU the host\n\n")
cat("\n\n")
cat("* 2. Memory Usage > 90%\n\n") 
cat("+ Add more heap memory to JVM\n\n")
cat("+ Investigate JVM Heap configuration\n\n") 
```
````

I can see the indentation for under CPU but I don't see the indentation under 2. Memory Usage. Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: First, if you are intending this to be included as raw-markdown, you need to escape the `>` sign, as it will otherwise be interpreted as "blockquote", plus you might want to include `{r, echo=FALSE, results="asis"}` as your chunk header (perhaps I misunderstood the intent). Second, if you want this to be two top-level bullets with two sub-bullets each, can you just add 4 spaces in front of `+`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is suggested by @r2evans. I would add that you do not need to call `cat` for each line, and that to escape `>` in `cat` you need to add `\\`:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
cat("  
1. CPU
  + \\>80%, investigate the load on JVM
  + \\>90%, add more CPU the host
    + Sub-sub bullet
2. Memory Usage \\> 90% 
  + Add more heap memory to JVM
  + Investigate JVM Heap configuration"
) 
```
````

If you wrote multiple `cat` because you wanted to add some R outputs, you can do it as is:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
pc <- 8*10
cat("  
1. CPU
  + \\>", pc ,"%, investigate the load on JVM
  + \\>90%, add more CPU the host
    + Sub-sub bullet
2. Memory Usage \\> 90% 
  + Add more heap memory to JVM
  + Investigate JVM Heap configuration"
, sep = "") 
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Indentation with cat engine using vertical bar (|) and any space after will be recorded. For example, 8x space will get a good indentation.

I used in this way:

```
cat("|        A Unidade de Escavação-UE", nome.escavacao...
cat('|         A Tablela \\ref{tab:' ,nome.escavacao,'}...
```

Note that when using (') you will have to put one more space in text.

And this is the result in pdf A3 paper:

[image]